# jQuery ajax - unable to post dynamic content

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery Ajax call to send form values to a PHP processing script. This call is triggered by a button in a modal. The form values themselves are the result of a previous Ajax call. I know how to make sure that a click event works on dynamically generated content, using .on(), but I don't know how to make sure that dyanamic form elements are recognized by the document. Any tips?

```
    $(document).on('click', '#goupdatenews', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).foundation('reveal', 'close'); // close modal
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'actions/ajax/editnewsajax.php',
            data: {
                newsArticleTitle: $('#news_article_title').val(), 
                newsArticleContent: $('#news_article_content').val(),
                newsPostDate: $('#news_post_date').val(),
                leagueID: $('#modal_league_id').val(),
                teamID: $('#modal_team_id').val(),
                articleID: $('#this_article_id').val()
            }
        }).done(function(html) {
            $('#newsposterror').replaceWith(html);
        });
    });
```

To clarify, this script is to submit an edited article, which sends the data to the database update routine (editnewsajax.php). The data is loaded from the database in a previous ajax call and written dynamically into the modal window.

More code: this is the data source, which is being dynamically written into the modal window by the previous ajax call. This is PHP.

```
$articleID = (!empty($_GET['articleID'])) ? $_GET['articleID'] : '';
    if(!empty($articleID)){
        $newsArticle = $db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = ?", array($articleID));
        echo "
            <div id='editnewscontent'>
                <div>
                    <label for='news_article_title'>Article Title</label>
                    <input type='text' name='news_article_title' value='{$newsArticle[0]['news_title']}' id='news_article_title' required />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for='news_post_date'>Post Date</label>";
        if($newsArticle[0]['post_date'] > $today){
            echo "
                    <label for='news_post_date' style='color:#ff0000'>This article has not yet been posted</label>";
        }
        echo "
                    <input type='text' name='news_post_date' value='{$newsArticle[0]['post_date']}' id='news_post_date' class='datepicker' data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd' />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for='news_article_content'>Article Content</label>
                    <textarea name='news_article_content' value='' id='news_article_content' style='min-height:150px' required>{$newsArticle[0]['news_description']}</textarea>
                </div>
                <input type='hidden' name='modal_league_id' id='modal_league_id' value='{$newsArticle[0]['league_id']}' />
                <input type='hidden' name='modal_team_id' id='modal_team_id' value='{$newsArticle[0]['team_id']}' />
                <input type='hidden' name='this_article_id' id='this_article_id' value='{$articleID}' />
            </div>";
    }
```

And here's the GET params from the ajax call. Note that ArticleID has a value, but nothing else does. Even though the elements are visible on the screen, and exist within the source code.

```
articleID   14
leagueID    
newsArticleContent  
newsArticleTitle    
newsPostDate    
teamID
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean; is the `data` object using the same values for every click?

Comment: @CollinGrady - the data values will be changing, depending on which article is being edited. But the element ids for the data will always be the same.

Comment: Right I understand the intent, but I don't understand your question. You don't need to do anything to make dynamic elements be "recognized" by anything, normally.

Comment: If the first line of the script were $('#goupdatenews').click(function..., then this script would not run at all. Because that element was not present on document ready.

Comment: Yes, and you already have it as .on so that isn't a concern. If you're worried about things like `$("#someid")` not working, don't be. It's not the same thing. Those are evaluated at runtime, unlike events which are bound to a specific element. As such, events are replaced when the element is, but simple accessors don't care.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you close the modal before you get the input values and make the ajax call. I think that could be the problem.

Personally, I wouldn't close the modal until after the ajax call is successful, but you could try:

```
$(document).on('click', '#goupdatenews', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        newsArticleTitle: $('#news_article_title').val(), 
        newsArticleContent: $('#news_article_content').val(),
        newsPostDate: $('#news_post_date').val(),
        leagueID: $('#modal_league_id').val(),
        teamID: $('#modal_team_id').val(),
        articleID: $('#this_article_id').val()
    };
    $(this).foundation('reveal', 'close'); // close modal
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'actions/ajax/editnewsajax.php',
        data: data
    }).done(function(html) {
        $('#newsposterror').replaceWith(html);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice thought. However, this code does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this issue turned out to be something really dumb - the ID selectors referred to in the Ajax call turned out to not be unique. Changing the ids to a different name fixed everything.

Mods,feel free to delete this - there's nothing in this question that would have led me or anyone else to the correct solution.